# Why won't this program work in release mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <fstream>    
#include <stdlib.h>   // includes the "atoi" function
#include <string>     
using namespace std;  

#include <sstream>;

int main()
{
   std::fstream f;
   f.open("file.in", std::fstream::in);

   // read data
   int count = 0;                 
   std::string line = "";

   getline( f, line, '\n' );         
   count = atoi( line.c_str() );     

   f.close();
   f.open("file.in", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);

   // write data
   ++count;

   f << count << endl;

   f.close();




   return 0;
}
```

This works in debug mode in Visual Studio but when I run it as an application it doesn't work.  I've initialized all variables so I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: In the future for a question like this, please give some detail on what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
 f.open("file.in", std::fstream::in);
```

Make sure file.in is in \bin\release

I also advice your to use try/catch statements and print your errors

Comment: I was checking the wrong file in a different folder.  This info helped me to open the correct file.in inside the release folder.  Thanks!

Comment: Randomly catching exceptions would not have helped here - there is no exception thrown on opening a non-existant file, reading from it, or closing it (unless you take special steps to configure the object to throw an exception on those errors).  However, checking the state of the `f` object after trying to open a file is a great idea.